# Regex Pattern 1-100 or N/A

Tags: .net, regex

Working on a project and hoping that someone could help me.  Would anyone be kind enough to show me how I can validates 1-100 or n/a (na).  We would like people to enter n/a or na instead of 0 (zero).

This is what I have for numbers but not sure how to include the na.

`(?:\b|-)([1-9]{1,2}[0]?|100)\b`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what you already have done to solve this problem so we can help you with errors you are facing when solving that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another alternation .
Something like  `^\s*([1-9]\d?|100|n/?a)\s*$`

Explained

```
 ^ \s* 
 (                # (1 start)
      [1-9] \d?        # 1 - 99
   |  100              # 100
   |  n /? a           # na or n/a
 )                # (1 end)
 \s* $
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for including the explanation.